# NSURLSession in background didCompleteWithError

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8

I'm fighting with NSURLSession upload & download, everything seems to work if not for the fact that, for example, at in the background of 100 files sent (upload) the :

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

not always invoked by the system, regardless of the file sent correctly.

More is almost always invoked at the end of the session ...

It is normal behavior or am I making mistakes ... ??

I also did some testing using AFNetworking but I always get the same behavior.

thanks !

Comment: Have the same problem.

Comment: Did you try to invalidate the session before create a new one? this that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262564/nsurlsession-didcompletewitherrorgets-called-with-nserror-is-nil/37240344#37240344

Answer (score 1):

In my case delegate method `func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)` was not called in **Swift 3.0** because it still depends on **Objective-C**. So please use next code for delegate method:

```
@objc(URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:)
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
  //your code here
}
```